# Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages for a language that includes a constant

Tags: regular-language, formal-languages, pumping-lemma

If I have a language like this:

L1 = {a^128 b^n a^n | n >= 0}

and I have to prove it is not regular, is it enough to prove b^n a^n is not regular, thus the whole expression is not regular, since a^128 is finite?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since regular languages are closed under [right and left quotient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_a_formal_language), and a finite language is regular.